# Import XML with JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a panel, that when clicked opens up and displays data. I would like to have the data come from a XML file.

The JavaScript function that I was using to display html text worked, so I was trying to use that function, but modify it to bring over the XML from another file.

The JavaScript function from the JS file:

```
function nameFunction () {document.querySelector("#collapse1> .panel-body").innerHTML = "Name works"};
```

The XML from the XML file

```
<dashboard>
    <name>name goes here</name>
</dashboard>
```

The html file that calls the JS function:

`<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" onClick="nameFunction()" >Name</a>`

Can the .innerHTML method be used for this task? If so, can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
   function nameFunction () {
        var xmlText = "<dashboard>"+
            "<name>name goes here</name>"+
            "</dashboard>";
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText,"text/xml");
        document.querySelector("#collapse1 > .panel-body").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
```

hope this can help you ! (this works)

Comment: No, it's not. I updated 'file.xml' to reflect the actual file name. But it's not passing the data. Should I include a link to the XML file in the http file or JS file? I ask because I've never done this before.

Comment: `DOMParser().parseFromString(text,..)` takes string not file, so you can read xml file first into string & pass it to this method.

Comment: quit the idea of using DOMparser, instead use XMlHttpRequest()

Comment: var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();xmlhttp.open("GET",xmlFile,false); var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

Comment: Is this what the code should look like?

function nameFunction () {var parser = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText,"text/xml");
        var name = xmlDoc.getElementByTag('name');
        document.querySelector("#collapse1 > .panel-body").innerHTML = name;};

Comment: We posted at the same time. I'll review your comment.

Comment: the above comment is what you asked for( can read an external xml file)

Answer (score 0):

```
        function nameFunction (){
            var xhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Create an instance of XMLHttpRequest object. 
                //code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xhttp  =  new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5 
               xhttp  =  new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", "data.xml", false);
            xhttp.send();
            var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
            document.querySelector("#collapse1 > .panel-body").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
```

this works in firefox,(not in chrome - chrome doesn't have XMLHttpRequest API I guess)
`so now you can parse xml file`

Comment: *Never* use `innerHTML` as it fails to register the `id` attributes of "imported" nodes. Learn to use `importNode`, `appendChild`, `insertBefore`, `replaceChild`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

you can import files using script tag.

```
<script id="xml" type="notjs" src="XX.xml"></script>
```

---

var xml = document.getElementById("xml");

Is this what you want?